# Running my node.js server with forever. Is it safe for hardware?

Tags: node.js, forever

I recently deployed a node js server using forever running it as a debian server, simply using the command ' forever start app.js' . Is that safe for my hardware? I mean If a lot of requests get pulled in and my computer won't be able to handle them will forever stop preventing damage that would have occured if computer got too hot?

Comment: Forever will do nothing, if your CPU gets too hot. Modern motherboards should just shutdown before your CPU takes damage.

Comment: @Sirko do you know any way to measure the computing needs of my node js app? I think it is called 'ms' or sth.

Comment: For computing needs, monitor CPU usage, memory usage and response times. For a basic monitoring these indicators should be enough.

Comment: @Sirko I mean, is there any kind of module I can run my app through and get a representative value of how much effort pc needs?

Comment: Nothing as simple as just putting your app in and it returns "you need 2 2ghz cpu cores and 4gb of ram".

Comment: @Sirko Ok, I was using heroku for a small period and I remember they used something to calculate ms of an app. I guess I will have to google to find out. Thanks!